# ASP.net: Using .NET Technologies to develop robust web applications, what tools do I need?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, mobile, jquery-mobile

Looking for a rundown of all the tools available that will allow me to develop mobile websites using the .NET stack. I'm likely going to be using MVC 4 and jQuery Mobile, but what else do I need to be thinking about as far as getting all devices compatible. Keep in mind, I'm talking about web sites, not native apps right now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am working o a website that I hope to make it work on most mobile devices without me making any changes and I have to say that I am mostly pleased with Twitter Bootstrap for this:  http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio is all you need to write the apps themselves.  The [Web Essentials](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/6ed4c78f-a23e-49ad-b5fd-369af0c2107f) VS extension is really handy with working on web related stuff, so I'd suggest taking a look at and installing it.  Jquery/Jquery mobile is probably your best bet for client compatibility as far as JavaScript goes.

Now, that's all you need to MAKE the site, but for testing, you should really use actual mobile browsers.  One way of course is to get your hands on an actual iOS or Android device to try out mobile safari, mobile chrome, etc.  The other way is to download the SDKs and development tools for iOS and Android, which come with the [iOS SDK and XCode](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/index.php) and the [Android SDK and Eclipse](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html), respectively.  You can use the emulators, which are normally used for app testing, to run the mobile browser on the fake device on your PC, which will give you a more real-world way of testing the site's look as well as touch functionality inherent in mobile browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio. Especially [Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads), highly optimized for mobile web.

[Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) Projects for support across platforms (not web app, but regular apps).